# How To Create 1 SBOM File For Android Multi Module Project

Tags: android, libraries, android-multi-module, sbom, cyclonedx

I am using cyclonedxBom to create SBOM file, I have 3 modules and I added for each module in the gradle file configs to generate the SBOM so in the output I got 3 SBOM's.

[image]

My question is how I can generate 1 SBOM file for all the project that will include all the libraries from all the modules?